# Display a message at a specify currentTime of the video

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I want to add a button which advance the  to the next second of playing and then display a message. I'm having a hard time capturing the currentTime for the button then advance to the next second.

code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smzefeev/)

```
var vid, playbtn, seekslider;
  function intializePlayer(){ 
  vid = document.getElementById("my_video"); 
  playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
  seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
  nextSlide = document.getElementById("next");

  playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause,false);
  vid.addEventListener("timeupdate",seektimeupdate,false); 
  nextSlide.addEventListener("click",skipToNext,false); 
 }

window.onload = intializePlayer;
 function playPause(){
    if(vid.paused){ 
    vid.play(); 
    playbtn.innerHTML = "Pause";
   } else { 
   vid.pause(); 
   playbtn.innerHTML = "Play"; 
  }
 }

function skipToNext(value) {
  var video = document.getElementById("next");
  video.currentTime += value;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle differs from code you pasted. What is a updated code? And what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: There is also missing seektimeupdate function to make your code work